# Txt to XML Import

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to import a large number of xml files that have been saved as txt files in to sql.  I was hoping to use something like "openrowset bulk".  The intention is to parse out a number of tags eventually but importing it in to a table in the correct format would be a good start.  I can find lots of examples of importing txt files or xml files, but no way to import the text file in to a xml field type, can anyone offer some suggestions?

Regards

Comment: An XML file *is* a text file, the extension shouldn't matter.  What have you tried and why didn't it work?

Comment: Hi Alex, So far I haven't got very far....the only code I have come up with and which does read the file is   "SELECT 'log.txt' AS FileName,   
      '.txt' AS FileType,   
      * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'c:\sample\log.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document"  This does read the file but the output is nothing like what is in the file.